# Python nested objects unable to retrieve value in function

Tags: python

I am trying to build a tree structure that represents a parsed configuration file (the configuration file has a hierarchical structure to it).  I represented this as:

```
class configContainer():

    treeDict = {}
    instances = {}

class configObject():

    def __init__(self, name, configLine, parent):
        self.name = name                # Assign to the line number to make unique
        self.parent = parent            
        self.children = []
        self.configLine = configLine    # Actual line of the configuration
        configContainer.instances[name] = self
```

The `configContainer` contains a set of objects. `configContainer.instances` uses a key of "line#" to map to the object. `treeDict` does a similar mapping, but with a different key (I create `treeDict` after the entire container is created).

I then try to reference two objects inside two different `configContainers`. This works fine from `__main__`.  But when I pass the two `configContainers` to a function, instances always returns objects from `configContainer2`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":


    f1 = open('rfile', 'r')
    configFile1 = f1.read()
    f1.close()

    configTree1 = parseConfig(configFile1)
    configTree1.treeDict = createTreeDict(configTree1)
    zObject1 = configTree1.instances["line10"]


    f2 = open('sfile', 'r')
    configFile2 = f2.read()
    f2.close()

    configTree2 = parseConfig(configFile2)
    configTree2.treeDict = createTreeDict(configTree2)
    zObject2 = configTree2.instances["line10"]

    print "\n\nFrom __main__"
    print "###########################"
    print configTree1
    print configTree2
    print zObject1
    print zObject2


    compareConfigurations(configTree1, configTree2)


def compareConfigurations(tmpTree1, tmpTree2):

    print "\n\nFrom compareConfigurations"
    print "###########################"
    print tmpTree1
    print tmpTree2
    zObject1 = tmpTree1.instances["line10"]
    zObject2 = tmpTree2.instances["line10"]
    print zObject1
    print zObject2
```

Result is:

```
### From __main__

<__main__.configContainer instance at 0xb77a34ec>

<__main__.configContainer instance at 0xb740a68c>

<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb740e3ac>

<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb7414bcc>


### From compareConfigurations

<__main__.configContainer instance at 0xb77a34ec>

<__main__.configContainer instance at 0xb740a68c>

<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb7414bcc>

<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb7414bcc>
```

I can't figure out why I am always getting back the 0xb7414bcc object from inside `compareConfigurations`?

Comment: What do you think `class configContainer():`does, as opposed to `class configContainer:` or `class configContainer(object):`? Also take a look at the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configContainer.instances` is a class attribute, so if you modify it for any instance of a class it will change for all instances of that class.  With your current code any time you create a new `configObject` with the same name it will overwrite the entry in `configContainer.instances` for that name.  You should either make `instances` an instance attribute of `configContainer` or make sure your `configObjects` have different names.

```
class configContainer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = {}
...
```

Here is a quick example of what is happening:

```
>>> cc1 = configContainer()
>>> cc2 = configContainer()
>>> cc1.instances["line10"] = "foo"
>>> configContainer.instances
{'line10': 'foo'}
>>> cc2.instances["line10"] = "bar"
>>> configContainer.instances
{'line10': 'bar'}
>>> cc1.instances
{'line10': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that `configContainer.instances` doesn’t access a instance variable, right?

if you want to refer to the wrapping class, you will have to do something like this:

```
class configContainer(object):
    treeDict = {}
    instances = {}

    def configObject(self, name, configLine, parent):
        return _configObject(self, name, configLine, parent)

    class _configObject(object):
        def __init__(self, container, name, configLine, parent):
            self.name = name                # Assign to the line number to make unique
            self.parent = parent            
            self.children = []
            self.configLine = configLine    # Actual line of the configuration
            container.instances[name] = self
```

Answer (score 1):

Something either in `parseConfig` or `createTreeDict` is corrupting your `instances` dictionary.

Notice that in main you get **both** `zObject1` and `zObject2` from `configTree1`:

```
zObject1 = configTree1.instances["line10"]
#...
zObject2 = configTree1.instances["line10"]
#
print zObject1
print zObject2
```

Which you said produces:

```
<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb740e3ac>

<__main__.configObject instance at 0xb7414bcc>
```

If you posted the source to `parseConfig` and `createTreeDict` we could get to the root of it.